# Is it possible to check number of HTTPConnection request made

Tags: python, request, urllib, uwsgi

I have a uWSGI server running in a linux VM node where multiple requests are made to  this.
At only some point there are some errors like ReadTimeout, HTTPConnectionPool and recovered automatically.

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.1.1.1', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /app_servers (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.
HTTPConnection object at 0x7f16e8a89190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',))
```

Is it due to requests exceeded ? or some network lookup issue.

I tried using netstat and sar command to identify the root cause, but CPU and IO stats are fine.
No of establisbed connected(ESTABLISHED) and CLOSE_WAIT state requests are also less. Not sure how to check for the past time.

How to check the number of http connection made at that point of time or why the HTTPConnectionPool (Max url exceeds)error occurs

Comment: `Network is unreachable` means that you are trying for reach a host to which there is no route. It happens when you gave the wrong host or there is a network problem.

Comment: There is less chance for wrong host because it occurred only once during the continuous scheduled run and recovered automatically